# Correct usage of Java System.currentTimeMillis() method?

Tags: java, factorial, language-concepts

I am comparing the time to compute both iterative and recursive factorial procedures in Java. I am trying to use the `System.currentTimeMillis` method to compare the time it takes for each algorithm to compute, but I can't seem to calculate the difference. I am not sure what the proper way to use this method is, but any event here is what I am trying to achieve in my code:

```
// ... more code above

System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
int integer = readInt();
System.out.println();

// demonstrate recursive factorial and calculate
// how long it took to complete the algorithm
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
int fact1 = factRecursive(integer);
long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.format("Result of recursive factorial %s is %d\n", integer, fact1);
System.out.format("Algorithm took %d milliseconds\n\n", (time2 - time1));

// ... more code below
```

Here is the output:

```
Please enter an integer: 25

Result of recursive factorial 25 is 2076180480
Algorithm took 0 milliseconds

Result of iterative factorial 25 is 2076180480
Algorithm took 0 milliseconds
```

Clearly I must be doing something wrong here, as the amount of time expected to compute factorials for both cases shouldn't be zero.

EDIT: Here are my solutions for factorial, if anyone is interested (not particularly unique, but here they are anyway):

```
// factRecursive uses a recursive algorithm for 
// caluclating factorials.
public static long factRecursive(long n)
{
    return n = (n == 1)? 1 : n * factRecursive(n - 1);
}

// factIterative uses an iterative algorithm for
// calculating factorials.
public static long factIterative(long n)
{
    long product = 1;

    if(n == 1) return n;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        product *= i;

    return product;
}
```

And is some output. Surprisingly, the recursive version holds up well. It isn't until about 39! that the iterative version starts performing noticeably better.

```
Please enter an integer: 39

Result of recursive factorial 39 is 2304077777655037952
Algorithm took 5828 nanoseconds

Result of iterative factorial 39 is 2304077777655037952
Algorithm took 5504 nanoseconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well-written factorial function should execute very quickly for n = 25, so having it run in approximately 0ms isn't terribly surprising.  You have three options:

1. Use a larger n.  This will cause the factorial function to take longer, and give you something to measure.
2. Measure time in approximate nanoseconds rather than milliseconds, using [System.nanoTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).
3. I recommend doing both 1 and 2.

As other answerers have pointed out, you are indeed subtracting end from start, which is backwards.  Obviously, you should fix that too.  But that change only affects the *sign* of the result, not the absolute value.

---

**EDIT**: Just to see how fast it is to find the factorial of 25, I wrote this Python implementation

```
>>> def fact(n):
...     def _fact(n, acc):
...             if n == 1:
...                     return acc
...             return _fact(n - 1, n * acc)
...     if n < 0:
...             return 0 # Or raise an exception
...     if n < 2:
...             return 1
...     return _fact(n, 1)
... 
>>> fact(25)
15511210043330985984000000L
>>> import timeit
>>> t = timeit.Timer("fact(25)", "from __main__ import fact")
>>> print t.timeit()
6.2074379921
```

Even though Python is an interpreted dynamically typed language without tail call optimization, a simple recursive solution with an accumulator can find `fact(25)` a million times in 6.2 seconds on my machine.  So the average execution time is 6.2 microseconds.  Not a chance of measuring a substantial difference between an iterative and recursive solution on a single run with millisecond clock precision.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was wondering the the execution time might be much quicker than this, so I tried a larger number. But it seems there will be an integer overflow if i use to large of a number for `n`.

Comment: @Dylan You'll need to use a long rather than an int in order to represent larger factorial values.  If you try to take the factorial of a number that's too big, you'll have to switch to [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which allows arbitrary-sized integers and thus can represent the factorial of pretty much any number you throw at it.  Just be aware that, although I expect an equal effect for both solutions, this *will* slow down factorial compared to native ints and longs.

Comment: Running a few unit tests on my Java program -- I noticed that the performance of the iterative version was better overall, especially once I tested for large numbers, while the recursive version was better for smaller values; I am curious to know what the big-O of both these algorithms are.

Comment: @Dylan If you're implementing factorial in the "classic way" i.e. multiply the numbers 1, 2, ..., n together somehow, the Big-O will be the same for both implementations.  However, making a method call is more expensive than jumping to the beginning of a loop, so I would expect the recursive solution to be slower than the iterative solution by a constant factor.

Answer (score 4):

The resolution of `System.currentTimeMillis()` can vary, depending on your system; it appears that your algorithm is too fast to measure with this timer.

Use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) instead. Its accuracy is also system dependent, but at least it is capable of high resolution time measurement.

Just-in-time compilation can have a big impact on performance, but most virtual machines require a method to be invoked many times before recompiling it. This makes it difficult to get accurate results from this kind of micro-benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do (finish time - start time), you have it backward.

try this:

```
System.out.format("Algorithm took %d milliseconds\n\n", (time2 - time1));
```

Comment: Factorial of 25 isn't really all that large, the speed at which your hardware can compute that is probably really quick, instead of time in milliseconds try nanoseconds. `System.nanoTime()`

Answer (score 1):

very usual mistake. You should be subtracting time1 from time2.

It will help if you name your variables sensibly - for example `startTime` and `endTime` so you would know or at least spot that you have to do `endTime - startTime` as `endTime` > `startTime`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your fast recursive may not be doing such a heavy processing after all.

Please use `System.nanoTime()` instead. It returns nano seconds

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

nanoTime()
Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

---

Another way to test is by iterating your factorial say a 1000 times. then divide the time difference by 1000.00 (double)

Comment: I would include a Javadoc from version 7 and version 6 is soon to be EOL.

Comment: I would ignore the first 10000 as they might not be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

To get a meaningful timed result you need to repeat it, and ignore, at least the first 10,000 times you call a method (so the code is compiled) and you need to run it for a further 2-10 seconds (repeatedly).